# how to get the encoded url to pass in social sharing url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application where I have blogs page. I have added a social sharing button to my blogs page. But my problem is how to get the encoded URL and pass it to the social sharing URL. I am referring to this article. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/sharing-url-on-facebok-using-Asp-Net/. Here in this article the url is predefined. but I need to get the url dynamic. How do i get the url and pass to social sharing url?

Here is my code:

```html
@model Blog.Models.Mybolgs
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.br_title + " : Travel Blogs";
}
<ul class="ct-socials">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/conference2014/#Register&p[images]=&p[title]=&p[summary]=">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=YOURURLHERE">
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<URL>&description=<TITLE>">
            <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="grid-11 left">
    <div style="padding:1px">
        <img class="polaroid" src="~/Imgaes/polaroid.png" />
        <p>
            @Html.Raw(Model.br_message)
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create sharing buttons for your blog you need the URL of the page which you want to share. To get the URL of the page you can use *@Request.Url*. In some links, you need also add some other information from your model. Let's look at them one by one.

**Facebook:**

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=@Request.Url">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </a>
```

**Twitter:**

```
<a href="@string.Concat("https://twitter.com/home?status=","%0A",@Request.Url)">
        <i class="fa fa-Twitter"></i>
    </a>
```

**Linkedin:**

```
<a href="@string.Concat("https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=",@Request.Url, "&title=",@Model.TitleOfPost,"&summary=",@Model.PostSummary )">
        <i class="fa fa-Linkedin"></i>
    </a>
```

**Google Plus:**

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=@Request.Url">
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
    </a>
```

Comment: How do I get @Request.Url?

Comment: you don't need to change anything. just copy them. @Request.Url is Razor c#. To become more familiar with this function you can visit this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.url?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you've provided the URL using viewmodel properties as in below example:

```
public class Mybolgs
{
    public string UrlAddress { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

And assign site URL inside controller action like this:

```
var model = new Mybolgs();
model.UrlAddress = "https://example.com/path/to/share";
// other properties

return View(model);
```

Then you can use [`@Url.Encode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.encode?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) helper to insert them as query string parameter(s) inside `href` attribute of anchor links:

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=@Url.Encode(Model.UrlAddress)&p[images]=&p[title]=@Model.Title&p[summary]=@Model.Summary">

<!-- Google Plus -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=@Url.Encode(Model.UrlAddress)">

<!-- Pinterest -->
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=@Url.Encode(Model.UrlAddress)&description=@Model.Title">
```

If you want to get current page URL in controller action and pass it to anchor links as encoded URL, use [`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.absoluteuri?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Uri_AbsoluteUri) (or just simpler `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`) in place of hard-coded URL string:

```
var model = new Mybolgs();
model.UrlAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// other properties

return View(model);
```